# Flow type annotations are breaking jest tests

Tags: jestjs, flowtype

I'm wondering if I could get some advice on how to get around this. I'm using flow and jest on a library, but the flow type annotations are causing all of my tests to fail.

I have babel flow plugin, so I can run the tests from the transcoded dist folder, however this breaks any real time testing capability and is very cumbersome.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but if anyone could explain to me how to strip flow anotations at the time of testing that would be amazing!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're describing can be fixed by using [babel-jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/getting-started.html#additional-configuration), which teaches jest to first run your files through babel and then execute them.

Comment: Thanks, it still doesn't seem to work though :/ I experimented by adding this as well:   
"jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "verbose": true
  }

Comment: I think you'll need to share more to debug this. How are you running the tests? How are you building the flow code into runnable code normally (not while testing)? What error message do you see? etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would try [babel-jest](https://github.com/babel/babel-jest) and [babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types).

Just install them with `yarn add --dev babel-jest babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types` and then create `.babelrc` file with:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-flow-strip-types"]
}
```

Now your Jest based tests should work without any other configuration. Just execute `yarn jest` or whatever command you used to use to start them.

Comment: It was written for Babel 6 if you are using 7 please refer to https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/packages/babel-jest, if you need further assistance please provide more details (e.g. error messages).